# Xades4j : SignedProperties reference not found

Tags: xades4j

I'm trying to validate Xades signatures using Xades4j.

Some of those signatures are generated by another tool (which is not Xades4j) and those signatures have no **Type** attribute in the **Reference** tag :

```
<ds:Reference URI="#signedProps">
  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
  <ds:DigestValue>KUAGWItLLNF6sNZ3kXy+/6oJyEo=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

i've got this Exception when i try to validate it :

```
xades4j.verification.QualifyingPropertiesIncorporationException: SignedProperties reference not found
at xades4j.verification.SignatureUtils.processReferences(SignatureUtils.java:221)
at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:132)
at com.jeremp.x4j.App.verify(App.java:110)
at com.jeremp.x4j.App.main(App.java:70)
```

I looked into the source code of SignatureUtils.java and it seems that the API use the **Type** attribute to identify the Reference tag.

Is there a way to validate this kind of signature with xades4j ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to validate those signatures using xades4j, unless you change the source code. I wouldn't recommend this since the XAdES spec clearly states that the Type attribute is mandatory. From section 6.3.1:

> Additionally, the present document MANDATES the use of the Type attribute of this particular ds:Reference
>   element, with its value set to http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties.